# Ember Data Save: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am prototyping an emberjs app. I am facing a problem when I try to save the data.

My model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
   id: DS.attr('string'),
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My Controller:

```
App.UsersAddController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   actions: {
      addUser: function () {
         var name = this.get('name');
         var description = this.get('description');
         if (!name.trim() && !description.trim()) {
            return;
         }
         var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {
            'id': 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16),
            'name': name,
            'description': description
         });
         this.set('id', '');
         this.set('name', '');
         this.set('description', '');
         user.save();
      }
   }
});
```

My template:

```
{{input type="text" placeholder="Name" value=name class="name-input"}}
            {{input type="text" placeholder="Description" value=description class="name-input"}}
            <button {{action 'addUser'}} class="submit">Submit</button>
```

The event bubbles up to the right controller. But fails to save. I am a beginner with emberjs. Please help me out.

Comment: What line is it happening on...

Comment: This can't be all your code. We don't see the `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember-data "Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990844/ember-data-cannot-call-method-hasownproperty-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `id` attribute from model definition.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  // no id
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @200OK, answer is changed.